# Android - Does SQLite Database Exist?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

How can I quickly check if a database exists in Android?

(not a Table - the entire database)

Comment: This is very common problem. Please check the following link. I think this will help you out. http://www.itsalif.info/content/check-if-database-exist-android-sqlite3openv2-failed

Comment: Please check [this document][1].. It may be helpful to you. [1]:http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your database and catch the SQLitException which will be thrown in case if database doesn't exist. Note that, you should not call the `openOrCreateDatabase()` method. See this post for details; [Query if Android database exists!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386667/query-if-android-database-exists)

Answer (score 2):

My way to check to see if your database exists is to open a file handle on it and see if the file exists. from my experience using "openOrCreateDatabase()" function will not throw an error if the db doesn't exist. take a look a the name "Open **OR** Create Database".  meaning if there's no db to open it'll just make a new one, so regardless of if there was one before there is one now. I think the only time you'll get an error thrown is if it can't do either. which from what the guy said I don't believe is what they are trying to test for, I think he wanted his program to know if the db was already there before hand, and not to automatically create a blank one if there wasn't. so Since all db's are stored as files, the first parameter in that open database command is the file name. So I think the best option is to check to see if the db file exists like so:

```
File dbtest = new File("/data/data/yourpackagename/databases/dbfilename");

//If you have Context, you could get the Database file using the following syntax
//File dbtest = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("dbfilename.db");


if(dbtest.exists())
{
  // what to do if it does exist    
}
else
{
  // what to do if it doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: must be : if(dbtest.exist())... your logic is not correct