# How to cout the number of SQLite databases in my app?

Tags: android, database, web-services, sqlite

Is there a way of count the number of SQLite Databases in my app without the need of inform their names? I need to make the following thest:

If there is one or more Databases in the app, I want to direct the user to the login screen, if not, send him to a sync screen where he informs some personal data and the database is downloaded from my webservice.

Ps: The app is a remote version of a web based system, and unfortanatly it needs to have one database per user and it's name isn't the same for everyone.

Comment: If the database has the same name then you can be sure that there will only be one of that database

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but no, the name isn't the same for everyone...

Comment: IF have have the db names, you can check if db with that name exists like so http://stackoverflow.com/a/3386736/4128945

Answer (score 0):

After the answers I've decided to create a standard database saving the user ID and name, so if it's empty the app opens the login screen, if not it opens the sync screen.