# How to check if a DB exists in Android?

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I am using Room API to implement a DB in my Android app. It seems that every time I load my app it tries to create the database again and again. Is there any way to restrict this?

```
 db = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, "database-name").build();
```

Comment: what type of variable is db ?

Comment: @GastónSaillén its an object of RoomDatabase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query if Android database exists!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386667/query-if-android-database-exists)

Comment: @HemantParmar . This is not a duplicate. Here I am using  the android Room API not the SQLlite one

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? How do you call an existing database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create database, the database `onCreate()` callback get called when the application starts. you can use the below code in app activity and that activity call in manifest file in application class call like used below code .

```java
public class AppActivity extends Application {

    AppDatabase db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "database-name").build();
    }

    public AppDatabase getDatabase() {
        return db;
    }
}
```

and add below line manifest file .. add below line in application tag

```
android:name="AppActivity"
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using db that is, in fact, a file. You can check, if it exists, this method could be helpful:

```
private static boolean doesDatabaseExist(Context context, String dbName) {
    File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(dbName);
    return dbFile.exists();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get count of entities in db (TODO app - example). entities > 0.

```
class App: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
        database = Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java, "database").build()
    }
    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: App
        lateinit var database: AppDatabase
    }
}
```

//DB class

```
 @Database(entities = [Task::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
       abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
       abstract fun taskDao(): TaskDao
}
```

//Dao interface

```
   @Dao
    interface TaskDao {
        @Query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tasks")
        fun getTasksCount(): Int
    }
```

//Model

```
@Entity(indices = [Index(value = ["title"], unique = true)], tableName ="tasks")
    class Task(
        var title: String = "",
        var description: String = "",
        var date: Date,
        @Embedded 
        var remind: Constants.RemindPeriod = Constants.RemindPeriod.MIN5,
        @Embedded
        var prior: Priority) : Serializable {
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var id: Long = 0}
```

//CheckDB

```
 private fun checkDatabaseState() {
        doAsync {
            val db = App.database
            val entityCount = db.taskDao().getTasksCount().or(0)
            isDatabaseNotEmpty = entityCount > 0
        }
    }
```

Comment: and do not forget:     implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1" or you will have RoomDatabase_Impl does not exist

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
if (!db.exists()) {
    // Database does not exist so copy it from assets here
    Log.i("Database", "Not Found");
} else {
    Log.i("Database", "Found");
}
```