# Android SQLite Database not working when returning to main activity

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm working on app that request user to use phone number to login and once they logged in, I'm passing that phone number from `LoginActivity` to `MainActivity` via `IntentPutExtra` evrything is working fine number is showing on top of the layout in Main activity. But when user starts making order for one of my service (provided in the app) and when it comes back to main Activity the phone number that users use to login is gone.

I tried to save that phone number in `SharedPreferences` and `Database` too but the same thing happens when user comes back to Main Activity the stored phone number is not displaying neither by `SharedPreferences` nor by `Database`.

Here is my `MainActivity` code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    SessionManager manager;
    TextView tvHinum;

    private Button btBikeServiceBook, btCarServiceBook;
    public SharedPreferences user_details;
    public static final String USER_DETAILS = "User_Details";
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private  static String USERNAME= "";
    public String passUserName , UserMob ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final Intent intent =  getIntent();
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       USERNAME = intent.getStringExtra(LoginActivity.USER_NAME);
        passUserName = intent.getStringExtra(LoginActivity.USER_NAME);
// Session Manager use to check first login
        manager = new SessionManager();
 /*
    USERNAME = passUserName;

    user_details = getSharedPreferences(USER_DETAILS, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    // Writing data to SharedPreferences
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = user_details.edit();
    editor.putString("key",USERNAME);
    editor.apply();
    // Reading from SharedPreferences
    String value = user_details.getString("key","");
    Log.d(TAG, value);

    */

        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        db.addContact(new Contact(passUserName, ""));
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
        List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
        for (Contact cn : contacts) {
            UserMob = cn.getName();

        }

        btBikeServiceBook = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btBookBike);
        btBikeServiceBook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BikeMakeModelActivity.class);                   
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btCarServiceBook  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btBookCar);
        btCarServiceBook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intntnt = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CarMakeModelActivity.class);                    
                startActivity(intntnt);
            }
        });



         tvHinum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHiUserNumber);
         tvHinum.setText(UserMob);         

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            this.finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
            manager.setPreferences(MainActivity.this, "status", "0");
            Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
  }
```

Here is My `DataBase Handler` Class:-

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new contact
    void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single contact
    Contact getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                        KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
        // return contact
        return contact;
    }

    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }

    // Updating single contact
    public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }


    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }


}
```

When I'm returning from `Final activity` to `MainActivity` I'm using

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

to clear stack. I thought this is the problem with Clearing Stack but after returning normally without clearing Stack same thing happens and no phone number displayed.

Comment: put your database or sharedpreference code in onResume since onCreate is already created and when you do a new Activity, when backpress that activity did not call the onCreate again.

Comment: but if the activity is not destroyed then its variables must have the last values stored. Because onResume is called only if the activity is onPause. Otherwise the activity is reCreated.

Comment: @SecretCoder i tried to set Database code in onResume but still Phone is not displaying when returning back.

Comment: @Tauseef Are you getting the value in 'passUsterName` when you  are getting value from intent

Comment: @SaurabhBhandariyes i'm receving it and it is displaying in it's textView on Top

Comment: can you breakpoint in the line of code at the database initialization. then try if it goes on that line again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your support guys. Now my app is working fine as @Secret Coder said i'm using my methods in `onRestart()` and `onPause()` and now I'm receiving the Phone Number Entered my user

Answer (score 1):

Tauseef
 You can get your id, password from LoginActivity to MainActivity like this ,
First you can store your id and pass in Sharedpreference when you enter your detail id and pass in LoginActivity like as.

```
        strId = edtEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        strPassword = edtPassword.getText().toString();

        SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("session", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("id", strId);
        editor.putString("pass", strPassword);
        editor.commit();
```

Second, then you can just get this value in your MainActivity like as.

```
        SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("session", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String strId = preferences.getString("id", "");
        String strPass = preferences.getString("pass", "");

        Log.e("Log", "Id---" + strId);
        Log.e("Log", "Pass---" + strPass);
```

Comment: Thanks for this help but i'm already receiving the phonenumber my porblem is when i'm returning back to Main activity then the Stored Value in SharedPrefrences gone.